# Did Syria use chemical weapons (in the recent April 2017 ordeal with 30+ civilian casualties)?

Tags: war, syria

My Apple News Feed blew up regarding the missile strike on the Syrian airbase in response to the "Chemical Weapon Attack" - which I put in quotes because while all the major news outlets in my news feed reported it as such, it seemed odd that they would attack civilians with chemical weapons ramdomly - then I saw a claim that the Russian government said Syria's airstrike was not chemical - instead that they targeted a terrorist warehouse which happenned to have chemical weapons inside.

What's the real story? The mainstream media's angle: Syria launches chemical weapons attack on civilians? Or Russia's alleged claim: Syria launches missile strike on warehouse which happens to contain chemical weapons?

Comment: Without more details about when, this question is impossible to answer. In what case certainly they had chemical weapons at one point, and they used them prior to that point.

Comment: @AndyT Oops, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know. Could be as presented by the US- the Syrian regime dropped [Sarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarin) on civilians. Could be as presented by the Russians- warehoused Sarin. Could be a '[false flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag)' operation by unknowns.

There is [evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghouta_chemical_attack) that Syria has used Sarin against civilians before. In 2013 there was an attack on Ghouta, Syria that killed somewhere between 300 and 1700 people. An investigation concluded that the attack was carried out by Syrian forces. Within a month of the attacks, Syria agreed to join the Chemical Weapons Convention and allow all its stockpiles to be destroyed.

Comment: Interesting.. so they kill 30 people and get 50 missiles dropped on them by the US but when they kill upwards of 300 people nothing big happens? Or was there a major response then too?

Comment: @Viziionary No there wasn't, but that was a different US president.

Comment: @Simon And the current president agreed with him at the time.

Comment: And skeptics even say that Syrian Airforce was already informed about the US strike as they took away their planes before the attack. Another question for the site maybe?